# Use git rebase and I get 'Nothing to do'

Tags: git, macos, vim

Same as title
I type "git rebase -i [commit_id]", and I got this:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/My_name/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

after type enter, I success to enter the vim editor.

```
  1 pick f694d12 test
  2
  3 # Rebase 3dad5af..f694d12 onto 3dad5af (1 command(s))
  4 #
  5 # Commands:
  6 # p, pick = use commit
  7 # r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
  8 # e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
  9 # s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
 10 # f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
 11 # x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
 12 # d, drop = remove commit
 13 #
 14 # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
 15 #
 16 # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
 17 #
 18 # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
 19 #
 20 # Note that empty commits are commented out
```

I delete the line 1 "pick f694d12 test" and save it, I just got a report

```
Nothing to do
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: f694d12 is the only commit to be manipulated, but you deleted it to tell git to do nothing.

Comment: @ElpieKay But shouldn't that remove the commit?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your test example was not very good. You could make more commits after f694d12 before doing a rebase test again. Keep the pick line to tell git to re-apply this commit to the new base, and delete it to ignore that commit. This is what an interactive rebase does, to use what you want and leave alone what you don't. As described in the comment lines, you could use other keywords to do other things.

Comment: @ElpieKay Huh?  I thought the way to _remove_ a commit during an interactive rebase was to delete the line containing that commit.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen after reading the comments I find I may have made some mistakes. If you don't want to apply it, use `d` or `drop`. I need to do some tests myself to find out what `THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST` means exactly. But one thing is clear, if you delete every non-comment line, git will do nothing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: if you delete a `pick` line it *does* drop that commit; but if the instruction sheet becomes empty, the rebase aborts. So you can only use this method to drop commits if there are other commits remaining, with commands to go with them. (The commands can still be "drop".)

Comment: @torek I have never seen this, probably because I always include some extra commits around the commits I want to alter when doing an interactive rebase.

Comment: @ElpieKay: correct, if you delete all instructions, interactive rebase aborts. The `noop` command was first added for defeating this, back in Git 1.6.0.3 (it was meant more for "rebasing" no commits so as to move a branch label a la fast-forward merge, than for dropping commits, but it worked for that purpose). The explicit "drop" command was added in Git 2.6.0 and is probably a better method in general.

Comment: @torek thanks for your info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you save an empty file during a merge / rebase, Git thinks you changed your mind and don't want to do anything. See the second-to-last line in the rebase todo file you provided:

```
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

To work around this, you can leave the commit line, but use the `drop` command. Your todo file will look like this:

```
drop f694d12 test

# Rebase 3dad5af..f694d12 onto 3dad5af (1 command(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Alternatively, if all you want to do is delete the last commit, you can do this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Or:

```
git reset --hard 3dad5af
```