# git rebase: "Nothing to do"

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a newly cloned repository and want to reword an old commit following [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message#amending-older-or-multiple-commit-messages).

When I run `$ git rebase -i HEAD~10` it just says "Nothing to do". I expected it to show me a list of the last 10 commits so I can start rewording.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460635/use-git-rebase-and-i-get-nothing-to-do) but there the issue is different.

How do I get the rebase command to work again?

Comment: Does Git at least open an editor with a sequence of commits for you? Or are you not even seeing this?

Comment: No, it only prints "Nothing to do".

Comment: `git log HEAD~10..HEAD` ?

Comment: @phd Yes, that lists the past 10 commits. There are enough commits in the repo to satisfy the rebase command.

Comment: Does configured editor work? `git var GIT_EDITOR` ? Or a fake commit — just to test the editor?

Comment: @phd Yeah the editor works (it's vi if it matters).

Comment: Well, very strange and I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @weltschmerz, even though I suspect this is highly unlikely, could you be in some kind of limbo rebase state? Check your `.git` folder to see if you have any `rebase`-prefixed directories or files, copy them away if so then try again. Otherwise I'm stumped too.

Comment: I ended up doing a fresh install of git as part of an update (was overdue anyway) and that fixed it. I guess we'll never know what caused this.